# The action ‘NAVIGATE’ with payload {“name”:“Home”,“params”:{}”} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a screen named ‘Home’?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am trying to navigate to a screen called "ConsumerHome" which is actually a bottom stack navigator from the last stage of the signup process (controlled by AuthNavigation) and I get the error:

```
The action ‘NAVIGATE’ with payload {“name”:“Home”,“params”:{}”} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a screen named ‘Home’?
```

I have added the component in question to the Navigation stack(AuthNavigator) as directed in the documentation but it still does not work. Here is my function call:

```
//This is the last screen in the signup flow

  function handleNavigate() {
    const url = userType === 'consumer' ? 'ConsumerHome' : 'InfluencerHome';

    navigation.navigate(url, { isVerified: true, _id: '' });
  }
```

AuthNavigator.tsx:

```
export function AuthNavigator() {
  return (
    <AuthStack.Navigator>
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="Root"
        component={OnBoardingScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="Signup1"
        component={SignUpScreen1}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="SignIn"
        component={SignInScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="Signup2"
        component={SignUpScreen2}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="Signup3"
        component={SignUpScreen3}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="Signup4"
        component={SignUpScreen4}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="PinInput"
        component={PinInput}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="Signup5"
        component={SignUpScreen5}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="Signup6Consumer"
        component={SignUpScreen6Consumer}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="Category"
        component={Category}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="AddSocialMedia"
        component={AddSocialMedia}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="AddProfilePicture"
        component={AddProfilePicture}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="Signup7Influencer"
        component={SignUpScreen7Influencer}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="SigninEnterPhone"
        component={SigninEnterPhone}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="SigninVerifyPhone"
        component={VerifySigninPhone}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="SigninEnterPin"
        component={SigninEnterPin}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="InfluencerHome"
        component={InfluencerBottomTabNavigator}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="ConsumerHome"
        component={ConsumerBottomTabNavigator}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

ConsumerBottomTabNavigator:

```
export function ConsumerBottomTabNavigator() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeTab"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme].tint,
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    >
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="HomeTab"
        component={ConsumerHomeStackNavigator}
        options={{
          title: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <FontAwesome name="home" size={21} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Payments"
        component={PaymentStackNavigator}
        options={{
          title: 'Payments',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <FontAwesome name="credit-card" color={color} size={21} />
          ),
        }}
      />

      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Services"
        component={ServiceStackNavigator}
        options={{
          title: 'Services',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Entypo name="notification" size={21} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I would appreciate any help as this has bugged me for days